Try solve this PDE $u u_x+y u_y=x+y$
Hi I have been trying to solve the following question with the characteristics method
$\left\{\begin{array}{l}u u_x+y u_y=x+y \\ u(x, 1)=x+1\end{array}\right.$
my steps:
$$\frac{d x}{u}=\frac{d y}{y}=\frac{d u}{x+y}=dt$$
then $y = ce^t$ and $\frac{d u}{dt}= x+ ce^t$ also
$\frac{d x}{dt}=  u $ then
$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}= \frac{d u}{dt} = x+ ce^t$
integrate this we have $x(t)= c_1e^t + c_2e^{-t} + \frac{c}{2}te^t$ then we would have that $\frac{d u}{dt} = c_1e^t + c_2e^{-t} + \frac{c}{2}te^t + ce^t$
$$ u(t) = c_1e^t - c_2e^{-t} + \frac{c}{2}te^t + \frac{c}{2}e^t$$
then $u(x,y) = x + \frac{y}{2} - \frac{2c_2 c}{y} $
with conditional initial we have $u(x,y) = x + \frac{y}{2}  + \frac{1}{2y}$
It's correct my solution, how to prove this is unique?

The correct solution is $u(x,y)=x+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{1}{2y}$.

@JJacquelin It's true, I got confused when replacing x and y in the solution, thank you
